# HR not providing relieving letter and salary slips

Tags: new-job, resignation, india, relieving-letter

I have worked for a company. Later on I've discussed with my manager about my resignation, and then I have resigned.

Since they did not have the internal portal to get the salary slips, HR was supposed to help me with the salary slips. As, company did not deduct the provident fund too. My new company is asking for the relieving letter and salary slips.  After repeated reminders previous organisation is not providing me the documents. Please help me with this.

Comment: Sounds like India...

Comment: @SolarMike It definitely is. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry to say, we cannot help you with this. We can say this is wrong and we can say you are entitled to get these, but we cannot enforce them anyway.

In practical life, you need to get a professional legal advice.

Answer (score 0):

I would report them you your country's or province's ombudsman:

For example the EEOC in the USA, CCMA in South Africa etc.

However, keep in mind that if the company did not deduct any amounts that are by law to be deducted for tax purposes, you will be liable for them for that time.